# Black red tree - creating a node with at most one child

Tags: graph-theory, computer-science, trees, data-structure

Let's assume I have a black red tree with integers values, for which I know the values of the nodes, but not the topology of the tree.

I can insert new numbers into the tree, but cannot insert numbers that are bigger than the tree's maximum node or smaller than the tree's minimum node.

When i insert a number, a new node with this number is inserted and than the tree stabilises itself.

What series of numbers could I insert, that will create a situation where one of my inserted numbers has one or zero children?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "insert new numbers into the tree" -- do you also want to create a new node in the process? Do you know where you're creating the new node? Does it not matter? Or are you just over-writing the value of one of the existing nodes?

Comment: Are you using the same node insertion algorithm as found in Cormen et al, Introduction to Algorithms, Section 13.3? Also this question might get a better answer at computer science stack exchange

Comment: If you are using integral values then there are cases when there is no such series. For example when there is no number that you can insert at all.

Comment: @Smylic I know, i refer to the cases where it is possible.

Comment: @Ido4848 Well, do I understand your question right: you want to get any sequence of insertions that makes at least one of inserted numbers appear in a vertex that has at least one nil child vertex independently of initial tree structure?

Comment: @Smylic, correct.